# Atmosphere error: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501

Tags: primefaces, websocket, atmosphere

After Glassfish running I get error in browser console (Chrome):

---

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/mcweb/primepush/result-from-api?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 501

Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending

---

GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2

Primefaces 4.0

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
     <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using atmosphere 2.1.4 version and put this snippet on your code:

```
<h:outputScript
  library="primefaces"
  name="push/push.js"
  target="head"
/>
```